# Как на Android заставить ProgressBar показаться уже в onCreate, в смысле как можно быстрее независимо от тяжести других элементов?

Tags: android

Есть `Activity`, в ней фрагмент, в этом фрагменте есть `WebView` во весь фрагмент, а также `FrameLayout`, в котором `ProgressBar` поверх `WebView`.

в `TheFragment.OnCreateView` инфлатится лейаут, затем происходит настройка `WebView`, также может происходить еще что-то - работа с базой там, затем там же вызывается `loadUrl`, а затем в `WebViewClient.onPageFinished` прогрессбар прячется.

А где же показывается прогрессбар перед всем этим? В том-то и дело, что он изначально `VISIBLE`.
Тем не менее, при открытии фрагмента проходит около полусекунды прежде чем он появится.
Как можно ускорить?

Не влияет ли то, что `WebView` в дереве расположен перед `ProgressBar` и на его создание уходит это время?

Верно ли понимаю, что `onCreateView` вызывается до каких-либо отрисовок, если да, то можно ли вызвать отрисовку уже в нем чтобы прогрессбар хотя бы появился (пусть и в зависшем состоянии).

Answer (score 0):

Показать прогресс до метода onCreate нельзя. 
Как правило нужно дать максимально быстро отработать метод onCreate с вынесением всего тяжелого в фоновые потоки.
План таков:

1. Запускаем активити. Все вьюхи кроме прогресс бара невидимые.
2. Даем отработать методу onCreate() в котором запускается обработка
   всех тяжелых задач в фоне. Передаем туда callback.
3. Вьюха отрисовывается и отображает прогрес.
4. Спустя какое то время по callback приходит информация b
   отображаеться на экране.
5. Скрываем прогресс бар.

В случаем с WebView можно повесить на него слушателя и показать только когда страница загрузиться.

Если работаем с базой, то вытаскиваем данных асинхронно, а не в главном потоке.